# How can I send a document to the document library of an On-Premise Sharepoint farm from my app?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am developing a NodeJS application which has a feature of sending a document to an On-Premise Sharepoint environment. Since MS Graph doesn't work with On-Premise environments how can I achieve this? The best approach I could find was to use Sharepint Rest APIs but I'm not sure how to perform authentication there. If there's any other method please let me know

Thanks.

Comment: do you have possibility to use c#?

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela No. It's a service on the web written in NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

are you using your application as a client side solution on the on-prem server?

If yes, you can use pnp/sp:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-sp-pnp-js-with-spfx-web-parts

If your app is somewhere else on the web or is running as a service, you can use ms flow and on-prem data gateway:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/gateway-reference

You should install the data gateway on the server, make a flow with http trigger, and save the file to Sharepoint in the flow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Our app is a service on the web so can the Sharepoint APIs work inplace of flow?

Comment: If you install and setup the data gateway, the flow will cominicate with your on premise sharepoint. 
Try this video tutorial, but instead of sending an e-mail you should save the file in the Sharepoint.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJj0E1C4z0c